# issue in selecting value in pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I think i am very near to my correct answer. I found one code on this forum like i wrote below.but it didn't work for me.Whats wrong with this code???

```
 <?php
include("config.php"); 

$start = 0;
$per_page = 10;
$targetpage = "manual.php?id=$id";  // This is my target page
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = 1;
} else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
if($page<=1)
    $start = 0;
else
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
........................
```

.............................
   .................?>

The answer which i saw contains id=42 in $targetpage = "manual.php?id=$id";But i don't understand why he used 42 there???

Then linking target page in next previous code as follows

```
      <?php


  if($page > 1){
     $prev = $page - 1;
     $prev = " <a href=\'$targetpage&page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
  } else {
     $prev = "";
  }
  if($page < $num_pages){
     $next = $page + 1;
     $next = " <a href=\'$targetpage&page=$next'>next</a> ";
  }
  else
  {
    $next = "";
  }
  echo $prev;
  echo $next;
  ?>
```

But it gives me error like \'manual.php is not found..But i have this file.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, try to use:

```
$targetpage = "./manual.php?id=$id";
```

if it doesn't work then it means you are specifying the wrong URL to your `manual.php` page, try to find the correct URL

and `id=42` it's an application specific parameter so it's related to that app so it's okay if you don't use it in your app.

Comment: Thank you ra_htial.But i specified correct url as that suggestion of forum's code.and i tried as u said above but it prints same error i.e /' ./manual.php not found......